# Верстка. Див не прижимается к левому краю

Tags: css, вёрстка

Почему блок не прижат к левому краю? Отступ от левого края около 10 px

Body:

```
 font-family: Arial, Tahoma; 
 font-style: normal; 
 color: white;
 font-size: 16px;  
 background: black;
 margin: 0px auto;
 max-width: 320px;
```

Элемент:

```
 <div style="position: fixed; height: 80px; width: 100%; text-align: center; border: 1px solid white">Главная</div>![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl0E3.png)![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1gDN.png)![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7R03.png)
```

Answer (score 1):

В   magin:0 px auto

поменяй auto  на что-нибудь.. он будет уже слева.

Comment: Все равно к левому краю не прижимается. Когда убираю "max-width" тогда прижимается

Comment: https://codepen.io/piotrazsko/pen/gKVWPE

Comment: просто закомментировал и откомментировал..и все применяется.. а то что у тебя ширина самого блока уже не верная.-это уже совсем другой вопрос